# Column access denied status: ACESS_DENIED When Uploading Custom Data

Tags: google-analytics

In order to track iOS device models in Google Analytics I am trying to upload a mapping file that will match device identifiers with readable models, as described here http://blog.bilue.com.au/accurate-apple-device-reporting-google-analytics/

The problem is that I'm getting the error in the title, even though I have the `Edit` permission for the property, and that apparently is the only thing that can cause that error, according to the docs:

[image]

This are the permissions that my user has:

[image]

Any idea what might be happening? Any other solution?

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the edit permissions page

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had the wrong custom dimensions in my file, but the error I was getting didn't say anything about this.